# in javascript how can i get a value indicating a character's general category like java Character.getType?

Tags: javascript, unicode

```
input char:a      (unicode:97) output type:2
input char:Space  (unicode:32) output type:12
```

in java i can use code: "int type = Character.getType(unicode)"
[Character.getType Api](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Character.java#Character.getType%28int%29)

Comment: You have to parse this file http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/extracted/DerivedGeneralCategory.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's the `nodeType` property which will tell you if it is a text node or an HTML element, for example. As far as obtaining the unicode category, I don't believe there is a native function for that. You can try this plugin which will offer unicode support for regex:

http://xregexp.com/plugins/

http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/nodetype.shtml

Answer (score 2):

There is a regexp plugin which supports Unicode categories: http://xregexp.com/plugins/.

Using that, you could create a function that checks for each category like:

```
var types = [
    'Ll', 'Lu', 'Lt', 'Lm', 'Lo', 'Mn', 'Mc', 'Me', 'Nd', 'Nl',
    'No', 'Pd', 'Ps', 'Pe', 'Pi', 'Pf', 'Pc', 'Po', 'Sm', 'Sc',
    'Sk', 'So', 'Zs', 'Zl', 'Zp', 'Cc', 'Cf', 'Co', 'Cs', 'Cn'
];

function getType(char) {
    var char = (char + "").charAt(0);
    for(var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        if(XRegExp("\\p{" + types[i] + "}").test(char)) {
            return types[i];
        }
    }
}

alert(getType(" ")); // alerts Zs, because " " is a space separator character
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/mYfCZ/1/

Comment: very cool, but this function depends on the regexp, it will slow.any faster way to do ?

Comment: This is a good solution. If you want it to be faster, nroe, you can simply cache the type for each character that the `getType` function has already found an answer to.